# Can I pass to the provide option data from lifecycle hook in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm working with Vue 3, using options API. I want to use provide/inject.

```
data() {
  return {
    table_columns: null,
   }
},

provide() {
  return {
    table_columns_data: this.table_columns
  }
},

created(){

  this.table_columns = Object.entries(this.table_data.fields).filter(field => {
    return field[1].is_column;
  });

},
```

When I inject `table_columns_data` on a child component, it is null. So it seems I cannot pass something build in the created() hook to the provide function.

Is there a way?

Comment: provide is not reactive by default, hence why you see it only providing the initial value `null`.  See the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject#working-with-reactivity) which explains how you need to wrap the value with `computed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy fix according to the [vuejs docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject#working-with-reactivity) is to change the provide, so it uses computed like here:

```js
import { computed } from 'vue'

//...

provide() {
  return {
    table_columns_data: computed(()=> this.table_columns)
  }
},
```

Here is a working example in [vue playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)